# Having trouble developing accurate CNN architectures

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

This has always perplexed me and I haven't been able to find helpful resources online.

So I'm working with image analysis and wonder if there are any rule of thumbs for setting up a CNN depending on what you plan to accomplish.

You have the MNIST dataset which works well with 2Conv2FC layers. Then you could attempt to analyze more complicated images or try to look for certain features within images.

At my current state, I really wouldn't know how to start these problems. Is it just trial and error?

Comment: What kind of images have you tried to get CNNs to work with? Are they some specific type of images that are causing the headache?

Comment: Right now, i'm working with an emotion greyscale dataset (CK+). 256x256 images with subjects showing some sort of human emotion. Using the 2Conv2FC, I'm getting about 30% accuracy. I could just guess and try random architectures but that doesn't seem ideal

Comment: How many target classes are there? Perhaps the problem formulation is too complicated. I could suggest you to try somehow simpler approach at first, before trying to get a CNN to handle the main problem in its whole complexity.

Comment: 7 target classes. Can you elaborate on that? Most of the research papers ive read have used CNNs. I'm just having trouble figuring out how/why they used that specific architecture

Comment: Regarding the architecture, it's often a trial and error process to find out which architecture works and which doesn't. An architecture that has been successfully used in a paper would be very reasonable starting point indeed, instead of trying random architectures. It's also possible that you have too few training examples. How many training examples do you have per class? Regarding simpler approach, I don't have experience of emotion classification, but you could possibly try to combine some of the classes if the examples withing the new class somehow represent a common (larger) entity.

Answer (score 1):

One good approach suggested in [cs231n](http://cs231n.github.io/) course is to use transfer learning, i.e. rather than engineering and training CNN architectures from scratch you can use one of the existing pre-trained [high-performing architectures](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22613/important-cnn-architectures) such as ResNet50 or InceptionV3, remove several top layers and re-train on your dataset. See the following [ipython notebook](https://github.com/ml4a/ml4a-guides/blob/master/notebooks/transfer-learning.ipynb) for an example.

It's also worthwhile to develop intuition for why CNN architectures designed the way they are. For example, have a look at VGG-16 [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf) that shows that increasing depth (the number of filters) with every layer results in higher accuracy, i.e. we obtain a [convolutional pyramid](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22449/benefits-of-a-pyramid-architecture-for-cnns). It's common to have a structure where convolutional layer is followed by ReLU activation followed by a max-pooling layer. InceptionV3 architecture uses multi-scale convolutions such as 3x3 and 5x5 simultaneously as well as 1x1 convolutions for dimensionality reduction. ResNet50 introduces skip connections that enable easier training of very deep convolutional networks. Similar skip connections can be seen in the DenseNet architecture.